# Bootstrap 4 Modal Opacity

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

So i'm using Bootstrap 4 Beta and want to darken the Background when a Modal is shown. I saw a post where i just had to add the css class

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
    position: fixed;
}
```

to my CSS file. They wrote i don't need to add the class to the div, just add it inside the CSS file. So if i just add it, it happens nothing. If i then add the class also to my modal div everything will get the opacity, even the modal itself. Does somebody know how to fix that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just update the current CSS class for the modal by overwriting it.

```
.modal-backdrop.show {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Where `.show` is the class containing the opacity for your background.

Comment: So i replaced the .in with .show but the outcome is the same.

Comment: You'll have to overwrite the CSS as well.

Comment: What do you mean with overwrite? I replaced it inside the css file

Comment: I've fixed it. The problem was that i triggered the modals with $("#myModal").show() i built a invisible button which will called by .click() which then call the original modal which is set in the data-target property

Comment: UPDATE: Realized i dont need to build a invisible button. I use .modal("show") instead of .show() now.